# Unexpected Output of Asterisks

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int num;
    int y [11];

    cout << "Enter the amount of numbers you would like generated: " << endl;
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;

    int x[num];

    for (int j=0; j<=num; j++)
    {
        x[j]=(rand()%10)+1;
    }

    for (int j=0; j<=num; j++)
    {
        switch (x[j])
        {
            case 1:
            y[1]+=1;


        }

    }

    for (int a=0;a<=y[1]+1; a++)
    {
        switch (a)
        {
            case 0:
            cout << "1: ";
            break;

            default:
            cout << "*";
        }

    }
}
```

This program is intended to print an asterisk for every time the number 1 appears in the array. However, the output is an infinite number of asterisks.

Comment: What does stepping through the code with a debugger show you is happening?

Comment: `for (int j=0; j<=num; j++)` -> `for (int j=0; j<num; j++)`, `int x[num];` VLA??, If no `case: 1`, `for (int a=0;a<=y[1]+1; a++)` is undefined behavior. Should call `srand` to seed random number generator before calling `rand`.

Comment: Minimum complete verified example?

Comment: This is not a free debugging service. Please try to debug your own code by using a debugger to narrow down the problematic code to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you still can't solve the problem. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ Also, variable length arrays like `int x[num]` is not a standard feature, at least not yet.

Comment: BTW, `int x[num]` is a Variable Length Array (VLA) and not standard C++, but a compiler extension.

Comment: A computer does not do what you "intend" it to do, but exactly what you told it to. When did you tell your computer to print an asterisk? Well, according to your `switch` statement, it's when the value of `a` is anything other than 0, and not when some particular value occurs in some array. And, the computer did exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: Why do you have a `switch` with only one `case`?  Convert to an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code.  Most importantly, your loops are going out of bounds of your `x` array, so the first loop is trashing surrounding memory.  And you are not initializing `y[1]`, so it will have a random value that your second loop then increments.  This is likely the reason why you see so many asterisks in the output - `y` probably starts out with a large value to begin with.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    int y = 0;

    cout << "Enter the amount of numbers you would like generated: " << endl;
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;

    vector<int> x(num);    

    srand(time(0));

    for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        x[j] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        if (x[j] == 1)
            ++y;
    }

    cout << "1: ";
    for (int a = 0; a < y; ++a)
        cout << "*";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which can be simplified by eliminating `x` and `y` altogether:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;

    cout << "Enter the amount of numbers you would like generated: " << endl;
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "1: ";
    for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        if ((rand() % 10) == 0)
            cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

There is no reason to use an array for `y` since you are just wasting 10 of its 11 slots for nothing.  It would make more sense to use an array only if you were actually tracking multiple counters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num, x;
    int y[10] = {};

    cout << "Enter the amount of numbers you would like generated: " << endl;
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;

    for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        x = rand() % 10;
        y[x]++;
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < 10; ++a)
    {
        cout << a+1 << ": ";
        for (int b = 0; b < y[a]; ++b)
            cout << "*";
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I found `y` superfluous, it boils down to `if (rand() % 10 == 0) { /* output asterisks */ }` -- maybe I read it wrong.

Comment: Hehe.. thanks, I guess weaving through the indeterminate `y[1] += 1;`, I took my eye off the ball. I guess I don't see how this is doing anything other than testing whether the generated number is divisible by `10` and outputting an asterisks if it is. In that case you don't need `x` or `y` -- just loop `num` times and output as asterisks as I comment above. What am I missing?

Comment: The OP's code uses `y[1]` to keep track of how many times `(rand() % 10) + 1` produces a value of 1. The final loop uses `y[1]` to determine how many asterisks to output. Yes, you can eliminate `x` and `y` if you want to simplify the code, but that is not the point of the OP's question

Comment: Yes, I get that, but what I'm saying is you produce the same asterisks output by simply looping `for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) if (rand() % 10 == 0) cout << "*";` It's fine to use both `x` and `y`, but for the code to accomplish the intended purpose, neither are required.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is tangled with extraneous variables, includes C features that are not part of the C++ standard, and invokes undefined behavior in a number of ways. There is nothing wrong with using as many variables as you like to store various values within your code, but thinking though what you need and limiting the number of different values you are tracking can help you keep your code logic on track. Let's first look at your integer array `y`.

```
int y [11];
```

Declares `y` as an array of `11` *uninitialized elements*. At the point of declaration, each element in `y` is indeterminate (meaning each contains only random garbage value), and any attempt to access an element of `y` before it has been initialized invokes *Undefined Behavior* -- you can have no confidence your code will act correctly from that point forward. Declared as a `int`, the indeterminate value held in each element could range from `-2147483648  to  2147483647` (the range of 4-byte integer values)

When you generate a random value that is divisible by `10`, you execute:

```
y[1]+=1;
```

Which is `y[1] = y[1] + 1;`. The problem however is `y[1]` is indeterminate at that point, it could be anything, you have just invoked undefined behavior, and your code can do anything from appear to behave correctly -- or SegFault.

Continuing, your next declaration is:

```
int x[num];
```

This is the declaration of a C *Variable Length Array* (VLA). VLA's are not allowed by the C++ standard, but are provided as a Gnu extension with, e.g., `-std=gnu++11`. If you are not using an extension that provides for a VLA, your code shouldn't even compile. Even if you are using an extension that provides for them, your compiler should be warning your that it is not part of the C++ standard.

If you want to use an array of unknown length, then dynamically allocate for `x` with:

```
int *x = new int[num];
```

You then have storage for to hold an array of `num` integers. (you should free the memory when no longer needed with `delete[] x;`)

Regardless how you allocate for `x`, as pointed out, you then attempt to read beyond the end of `x` with:

```
for (int j=0; j<=num; j++)
```

Arrays are indexed from `0` to `n-1`, so the proper `for` loop condition to control your iteration of each element using `for (int j=0; j<num; j++)`

If I read though your code correctly, you are simply attempting to output and asterisks `"*"` each time you generate a random number that is divisible by `10`. While not needed, you attempt to store the number of randoms divisible by `10` in `y[1]` (subject to the uninitialized issue addressed above). By using `y[1]` uninitialized, it could hold a garbage value as large as `2147483647` or even a value that is the representation of a negative number in a two-compliment system. So `y[1] += 1;` could be any value -- even negative.

Then looping `for (int a=0;a<=y[1]+1; a++)`, you could loop `0` times or you may end up filling your screen many times over with asterisks.

Moreover, while you are free to use as many variables as you like to track each value independently (up to the available stack and system memory available), declaring `int y[11];` to then just use the second element in the array `y[1]` does not make a whole lot of sense. You don't need an array at all. If you are just wanting to output an asterisks any time a generated value is divisible by `10`, you don't even need an `x`. All you need is the number of randoms you wish to generate. If you refactor and pair your code down to a minimum, you could write something much shorter that will do the job, similar to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main (void) {

    int num;
    
    srand (time(NULL)); /* seed random number generator */
    
    cout << "Enter the amount of numbers you would like generated: ";
    if (!(cin >> num)) {    /* validate integer input */
        cerr << "error: invalid input.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "\n1: ";
    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)       /* loop num times */
        if (rand() % 10 == 0)           /* divisible by 10? */
            cout << "*";                /* output asterisks */
    
    cout << '\n';   /* output POSIX compliant newline at end */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/asterisks_min
Enter the amount of numbers you would like generated: 20

1: ****
```

However, if you did want to store the series of `1` and `0` results from testing whether the generated randoms were divisible by `10`, you could simply allocate for `x` as discussed above, and fill the values depending on the result of your test `(rand() % 10 == 0)`. To validate your logic, you can output the result of `rand % 10`, and the value stored in `x[j]` to confirm that you are outputting the correct number of asterisks.

With only a bit of reshuffling of variables, and replacement of the unnecessary `switch()` statements with simply `if` clauses, you could do something close to what it looks like you were attempting originally, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main (void) {

    int num;
    
    srand (time(NULL)); /* seed random number generator */
    
    cout << "Enter the amount of numbers you would like generated: ";
    if (!(cin >> num)) {    /* validate integer input */
        cerr << "error: invalid input.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    int *x = new int[num];  /* allocate, VLA not standard in C++ */

    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {     /* loop num times */
        int v = rand() % 10;            /* rand mod 10 */
        if (v == 0)                     /* divisible by 10? */
            x[j] = 1;                   /* store 1 */
        else
            x[j] = 0;                   /* store 0 */
        /* debug output, rand % 10 & contents of x[] */
        cout << "v: " << v << "  ->  x[" << setw(2) << j << "]: " 
            << x[j] << '\n';
    }
    
    cout << "\n1: ";                    /* simply output prefix */
    for (int a = 0; a < num; a++)       /* then loop over stored 1's */
        if (x[a] == 1)
            cout << "*";                /* output * for each 1 value */
    cout << '\n';                       /* tidy up with newline */
    
    delete[] x;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/asterisks
Enter the amount of numbers you would like generated: 20
v: 6  ->  x[ 0]: 0
v: 9  ->  x[ 1]: 0
v: 1  ->  x[ 2]: 0
v: 1  ->  x[ 3]: 0
v: 3  ->  x[ 4]: 0
v: 8  ->  x[ 5]: 0
v: 0  ->  x[ 6]: 1
v: 3  ->  x[ 7]: 0
v: 9  ->  x[ 8]: 0
v: 8  ->  x[ 9]: 0
v: 2  ->  x[10]: 0
v: 5  ->  x[11]: 0
v: 9  ->  x[12]: 0
v: 9  ->  x[13]: 0
v: 8  ->  x[14]: 0
v: 3  ->  x[15]: 0
v: 0  ->  x[16]: 1
v: 0  ->  x[17]: 1
v: 3  ->  x[18]: 0
v: 2  ->  x[19]: 0

1: ***
```

Which, if I understood the ultimate goal of your code, confirms that you are outputting  `"*"` for each random value that is divisible by `10`.

Lastly, when using `rand()`, before you make your first call to `rand()`, you should seed the semi-random number generator. You can either use a semi-unique value like the number of seconds since epoch using `time (NULL)`, or you can provide a fixed seed that will allow you to reproduce the random set for later use and evaluation.